# pygtk, callbacks methods and controller

Tags: python, model-view-controller, user-interface, callback, pygtk

There is something that I don't understand in pygtk:

I try to build a gui to interact with a slqlite database in order to manipulate some distant network configurations on several servers.

So I make three files:

Mygui.py wich contains all pygtk instructions;
Mydata.py wich contains all sqlite manipulations
and finally Myapp.py which should conduct the interactions between Mygui and sqlite.

But I don't see how to implement the callback functions and their definitions:

with theses lines in Myapp.py:

```
 class Myapp():
   def __init__():
      self.data = Mydata()
      self.gui = Mygui()
```

...

and with lines like these in Mygui.py:

```
 class Mygui():
   def __init__():
```

...
self.Base_menu = gtk.Menu()
self.contenu_item = gtk.MenuItem('contenu base")
self.Base_menu.append( self.contenu_item )
... # others

```
       self.contenu_item("activate", contenu_callback )
```

I think ( probably false ) that "contenu_callback" should be in Myapp.py has it connect the database with the display, but I don't understand how to?

---

(edit after 5 minutes )

Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure if I understand correctly:
So what I understand from your last line is that in the module "MyGui.py",
I should add `"import Myapp.py()"` to be able to call
`"Myapp.activate_callback" ( "other.module" in this case being Myapp )`.

So globally I will have "Myapp.py" which contain "import Mydata" and "import Mygui" and also the Module "Mygui.py" which will contain "import pygtk" and "import Myapp".

I feel not very satisfied by the circular relation between "Myapp.py" which imports "MyGui" and "MyGui" which will import "Myapp".

Is this really what I should do to separate the gui proceedings from the application processing?

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks can be any callable, so, *where* you put them is up to you.

```
def activate_callback(widget, data=None):
    pass 
some_widget.connect("activate", activate_callback)


class SomeClass(object):
    def activate_callback(widget, data=None):
        pass
my_class = SomeClass()
some_widget.connect("activate", my_class.activate_callback)


import some.other.module
some_widget.connect("activate", some.other.module.activate_callback)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'm not sure if i understand correctly :

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how strict you want to be about the separation. If you'd prefer to be a bit loose about it, you could have myapp pass itself to the Mygui instance, then Mygui can call methods on Myapp:

```
class Myapp():
   def __init__():
      self.data = Mydata()
      self.gui = Mygui(self)
```

Or you can define a bunch of events on Mygui, and have Myapp register handlers for those events:

```
class Myapp():
   def __init__():
      self.data = Mydata()
      self.gui = Mygui()
      self.gui.connect("record-saved", self.record_saved_handler)
```

The latter is more decoupled but involves more ceremony.

Comment: thanks very much ; it's the last line "self.gui.connect ..." that i was searching for .

Comment: I just realised I forgot a detail from my answer. While what you're doing there is conceptually just another event, there's no rule that says you have to use pygtk's event infrastructure to send it through. You might have a list of callables in gui that Myapp adds itself to, you might have an interface that Myapp provides an implementation of, or you might indeed use the GUI library's event infrastructure.